# Will IRCTC refund after cancelling waiting list ticket?

Tags: india, indian-railways

I have booked a ticket in Tatkal from Mumbai to Chennai and my Passenger Status is waiting list CKWL 3. If I cancel the ticket will my money be refunded? Or if the ticket is not confirmed will the money be refunded?

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel your ticket your money will be refunded but a small amount of cancellation fee will be deduced. On the other hand if the ticket is not confirmed and you fail to cancel the ticket then no money will be refunded for you.